# MVC: Two form tags and one ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a single page on my MVC application. On this page, a user can enter their user name and password and click a login button, or the user can enter their first name, email address and click a signup button.

My initial thought was to create a ViewModel with `UserName`, `Password`, `FirstName` and `Email` properties, all with a `[Required]` attribute. Then having a view with two `Html.BeginForm()`'s. Although this would probably work, I have the feeling that when I post my data back to my controller, `ModelState.IsValid` will always return `false` since the ViewModel, is indeed, invalid.

So can someone tell me the proper way to handle a situation like this?

Comment: Each case has different validation rules: two separate forms with two separate view models.

Comment: If you want to use one model and one form for different types of log in I think that that you cannot have [Required] attribute on your model. You will always have some empty values. I also recommend separate view and separate model for each type of log in as @Jasen said.

Comment: Are you using AJAX or postback? If it's postback, some of the current answers are going to cause pain for you down the road.

Comment: @Jasen - This is true for the client side validation. But when I evaluate `ModelState.IsValid` on the C#/server side code, it will always evaluate to `false` because all the fields on the model are decorated with `[Required]` and only some of the model is filled out. Either the `UserName` and `Password` fields will be filled out and the `FirstName` and `Email` will be empty or else the `FirstName` and `Email` will be filled out and the `UserName` and `Password` will be empty. There is never a scenario where all the `[Required]` fields will be filled out.

Comment: @WillRay - It's postback

Comment: And that's why you need two different view models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented very similiar scenario in my project i think the best way of achievie this is to create a viewmodel that will have 2 child viewmodel's inside something like this:

```
public class AuthModelView
{
    public MemberLoginViewModel LoginModel { get; set; }
    public MemberRegisterViewModel RegisterModel { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}
```

MemberLoginViewModel:

```
public class MemberLoginViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
    [Display(Name = "")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }


    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

MemberRegisterViewModel:

```
public class MemberRegisterViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string RepeatPassword { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Then you create the View that will render 2 partial views

```
  @Html.Partial("MemberLoginSummary", Model)
  @Html.Partial("MemberRegisterSummary", Model)
```

Where the "Model" is your parent Viewmodel, then you will have 2 separated forms 
in one view. In your partial view you simply do something like :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginModel.Email, null, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "email", id="Email" })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define 2 view models.

Login view model:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Requried]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Requried]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Register view model:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Requried]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Requried]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Requried]
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }

    [Requried]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Login view:

```
@Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post)
{
    <!-- login form implements... -->
}
```

Register view:

```
@Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post)
{
    <!-- register form implements... -->
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    }
}

public IActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    }
}
```

Or, if you want only 1 model. Try to remove `[Required]` attribute. You can check it inside the action. Like this:

```
public IActionResult Login(YourViewModel model)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.UserName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Password))
    {

    }
}

public IActionResult Register(YourViewModel model)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.UserName) &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Password) &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.FirstName) &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Email))
    {

    }
}
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try different library then you can go with [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/)

FluentValidation provides elegant way to customize validation for single class for different methods.

For e.g

```C#
[Validator(typeof(LoginRegisterModelValidator))]
public class LoginRegisterViewModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string FirstName{ get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

You can have multiple rules defined for different actions
The validator class would look like this

```C#
public class LoginRegisterModelValidator : AbstractValidator<LoginRegisterViewModel>
    {
        public RegistryAddEditModelValidator()
        {
            /* Define the rule set to call them specifically inside contrller action parameter with CustomizeValidator Attribute */
            RuleSet("LoginRuleSet", LoginRuleSet);
            RuleSet("RegisterRuleSet", RegisterRuleSet);            
        }

protected void LoginRuleSet()
        {
           RuleFor(x => x.UserName).NotEmpty();
           RuleFor(x => x.Password).NotEmpty();
        }

        protected void RegisterRuleSet()
        {
           RuleFor(x => x.Email).NotEmpty();
           RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).NotEmpty();
        }
}
```

The Controller Action would look like this

```C#
 [HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login([CustomizeValidator(RuleSet = "LoginRuleSet")] LoginRegisterViewModel model)
        { ...
        }

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register([CustomizeValidator(RuleSet = "RegisterRuleSet")] LoginRegisterViewModel model)
        { ...
        }
}
```

Hope this helps you to validate different rule with same class.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the proper way is to have a ViewModel for each. Your underlying business logic and/or code talking to the database can still work with a single model if you want.

Your options are discussed well [here](http://stevemichelotti.com/aspnet-mvc-view-model-patterns/).

Although I would add that having more than one ViewModel on an MVC page is a pain. [Some guidance here on how](https://damienbod.com/2014/01/27/multiple-viewmodels-in-a-single-mvc-view/).